# while using cordova ionic How to avoid on going back to start page in android app

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to make a android hybrid app using cordova ionic. My app loads the provided given link on launch and everything is working as it should be.

In this app when I am using back button it goes back that is also **ok**.

But **problem** is when it goes back to starting page. My **starting page** is empty html file and the related ts file loads the website after platform is ready. How can I avoid my back button to exclude going to white empty html page. I tried reloading the white page with website but no luck.

**In Simple words I want to keep my back button functionality but at same time dont want to go back to starting page after which the website is loaded.**

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser,public platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
     let browser = this.iab.create('https://w3schools.com/','_blank',{zoom:'no',location:'no'});
     browser.show();
   });
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      let browser = this.iab.create('https://w3schools.com/','_blank',{zoom:'no',location:'no'});
      browser.show();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Use hardware Back Button API https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/hardware-back-button

Comment: Why create the in-app browser twice? Best to fire that code either in the constructor or in ngOnInit, not both.